# Want to redirect naked domain name to www.example.com using Route53, my buckets are there in s3 with the same name as domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

My website is opening correctly for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but when i am trying to create the recordset for example.com and it is appending the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), and its getting incorrect,

how to remove the appending part, or is there any other way to redirect naked domain to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) ?

Reverse is possible by adding www. But i dont want this.

You can see the beside the name the appending string is given in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you created a hosted zone with the `www` included.

Create a new hosted zone for `example.com` and migrate the contents of `www.example.com` into it (except `NS` and `SOA` records).

Once you have done this you will then need to update your registrar to use the nameservers for the `example.com` hosted zone.